# How to position equations similar to the figures and tables?

Tags: floats, equations

I am trying to change the position of the `equation`, similar to the idea of the specifier `[h]` of the `figure` and `table`.

Is there any specifier for the `equation` (or for the `align` environment) like there are for the `floats` such as `[h]` or `[t]`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...

Comment: Thank you!.....

Comment: You _could_ define a new float type for equations but that is not common, figures need `[h]` as they move but equations just appear where you place them so no `[h]` is needed normally, why do you need floating equations. Unlike images mathematics is normally part of the main document flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to place the equations inside the `figure` environment without `\caption` tag, and the `MWE` is:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{align}
a+b=c
\end{align}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: It works as intended, thanks. Latex successfully prints out the pdf but it also gives and error `You have forgotten to use \caption at \eng{figure}`.

Comment: Can you post your preamble part, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`

Comment: It is unfortunately too long for here to post. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: @Umur the standard classes do not make a warning like that. You could make a _small_ example (the document only needs contain an equation, and then you can delete from the preamble every package not needed to show th eproblem with that equation,)

Comment: It would be better to declare a new float type for equations rather than use `figure` as it is latex will float figures and equations together so a large figure that floats to the end will take all equations (but nit tables) to the end. If you declare a new float type then figures and equations would float independently.